# Joining Multiple MySQL Statements

Tags: mysql, join

I have multiple queries I perform that I would like to join together.

The first query converts a user supplied path into an id. Paths can have multiple ids associated with them so I want to ensure I get the most recently created id for the path:

`SELECT id FROM paths WHERE path=$path ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1`

Once I know the id number I can perform the rest of my queries.

I have the most recently created id for the path but I need to also verify I have the most recently created path for that id (sometimes they are not the same):

`SELECT path FROM paths WHERE id={id} ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1`

I'd like to include the id's rating and the count of votes though sometimes there are none:

`SELECT AVG(vote) AS rating, COUNT(*) AS count FROM votes WHERE id={id} GROUP BY id`

Finally I'd like to include everything from a third table about the id (the id is UNIQUE on this table so there cannot be multiple lines):

`SELECT * FROM places WHERE id={id}`

How can I best join these statements together?

Answer (score 0):

You can join them together into one query like this:

```
select pl.*, avg(vote) as rating
from (SELECT path, id
      FROM paths
      WHERE path = {path}
      ORDER BY created DESC
      LIMIT 1
     ) p left outer join
     votes v
     on v.id = p.id left outer join
     places pl
     on pl.id = p.id
group by p.id;
```

EDIT:

The first two conditions *do* seem redundant.  But, if you need them:

```
select pl.*, avg(vote) as rating
from (SELECT path, id
      FROM paths
      WHERE id = (select id from paths where path = {path} order by created desc limit 1)
      ORDER BY created DESC
      LIMIT 1
     ) p left outer join
     votes v
     on v.id = p.id left outer join
     places pl
     on pl.id = p.id
group by p.id;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but it doesn't include the newest path for the id (the second query). I know it seems redundant but it does do an important check: a new path might have been created for an id but a user might be querying using the older one in which case something special needs to happen.

Comment: @gordon, are you sure the id of `place` equals the id of `path`? I personnally just assumed the variable had the same name but the values were different.

Comment: @Sebas . . . The OP seems to get the `id` once, and then use it multiple times.

Comment: @Gordon, when running the above code, even though the path and id were selected they are not actually outputted, nor is the row count on the votes table.